# Tracking user statistics on file server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

How can I track remote user statistics on a file server? Statistics like Disk Queue Lenght and such. I got an idea of using MAC address's since they were static to track the users, however, I wrote scripts to calculate disk queue lenght but cannot tie the two so it can track the disk queue length per user. I am using a Microsoft 2008 R2 Server. Please help.

Comment: Not sure this is even doable, but the things that MS does stats on never ceases to amaze me!

Comment: You can use perfmon to track system queue lengths, of course... but a per user disk queue length sounds like a profoundly useless measurement, TBH.  Maybe if you tell us what problem you're actually having, someone will be able to provide a more useful approach to solving it.

Comment: 100's of users are on the fileservers, using them for everything, from running scripts,to opening and writing files, these users are sending a lot of requests and in turn increasing the disk queue lenght, i would like to monitor the user who is causing such increase and then warn the user or disconnect the user.

Comment: I already have disk queue length scripts written and how to identify the user (in python) but cannot tie the two together.

Comment: Like I said I don't think this info is tracked at all, but if it is you'll need to look into event tracing to dig this stuff out.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to utilize the File Server Resource Manager to run reports on files and users as well as define quotas and other limiting controls:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753190(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: Love it.  Summer of Love my ass.